# Class not being built using Scala Eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to use the Scala Eclipse plug-in (version 1.1.0, which appears to be the most current) with version 3.7 of Eclipse on Mac OS X 10.6.8. I've copied the "Hello, World" program from a [tutorial website](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Scala/article.html). I was able to build the program successfully using the command-line `scalac` compiler. However, when I attempt to run the project as a Scala application from within Eclipse, I get an error like so:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/vogella/scala/first/Hello
```

with a bunch more stuff following. Looking in the relevant directory structure in my Eclipse workspace directory shows that the associated `bin` directory is completely empty. However, there are no errors (and indeed no messages of any sort) when I select "Build Project" from the menu.

As far as I can tell, my Eclipse installation is otherwise functional. I can, for instance, successfully build and run Java projects.

Any tips on where to start with troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated. Trying the suggested solutions in the most [relevant-seeming existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535320/noclassdeffounderror-using-scala-plugin-for-eclipse) didn't work.

**EDIT** to add: There isn't anything in the Error Log window except this:

```
System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to 
local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be 
overwritten using the values from the preferences
```

which doesn't strike me as terribly relevant. The full text, as copied from the tutorial, of the `Hello.scala` file, is

```
package de.vogella.scala.first

object Hello {
  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

and the package the file is a part of is called `de.vogella.scala.first`.

Comment: [Scala-Eclipse](http://www.scala-ide.org/) has been under active development. If you can upgrade, I'd recommend trying the *much* improved Scala IDE 2.0.0-beta9, or maybe even one of the nightly builds.

Comment: Do you have anything in the Error Log? Maybe the presentation compiler is crashing for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed Kipton Barros' suggestion from the comments, and installed the 2.0.0 beta of the Scala IDE plug-in for Eclipse. While I find it slightly strange that switching from a final release to a beta release resolved the issue, resolve the issue it did.

(Too bad I can't accept a comment as the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the package declaration in your scala file match the packages in eclipse.